# VBA Exit inner loop but returns to inner loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested

I am simply using an outer loop that loops through the subfolders in a directory, & creates a master file in each subfolder reflective of the files in that subfolder; the file structures are all identical so I only need one file to base on as a template for the master file, which will hold all the accumulated data from all files in each subfolder. File structure in other folders are different so that is the reason I need master file in each subfolder.

Since I am only wanting to use one of the files in the inner loop subfolder to copy over the headers and name of the file (Name & "Master" to rename file) however on using 'exit for' the loop returns back to the inner loop and loops through all the other files, which I don't want.

There is likely a better way to do this however this is what I have got and wonder if anyone can suggest why the inner loop does not return to the outer loop to go to the next subfolder when it gets to exit for statement in the inner loop?

I am just using the outer loop to initialise each folder and am not doing anything else within this loop except calling the inner loop.

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders

    Dim IsExecuted As Boolean
    Dim Item
    Dim filename
    Dim lastcol As Integer
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Files  **<<<< returns here**
        If Not IsExecuted Then
            Exit For
        Else
            filename = Item.Name
            Call CreateMasterCopy(removename(filename), strStartDir, SubFolder.Name)


             Call findcolumncount(Item)
             IsExecuted = True
        End If
    Next
Next  **<<<< returns to inner loop from here**


End sub
```

Thanks for any constructive feedback

Andrew

EDIT: the code below now does exactly what I want with the inner loop now gone.

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
Dim SubFolder
Dim filename As String
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders

    'search for file with Pattern at end to load this file into the filename variable
    filename = Dir(SubFolder & "\* - MyPattern.csv")

            Call CreateMasterCopy(removename(filename), strStartDir, SubFolder.Name)


Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify when `Exit For` is hit, the macro goes to the next `Item`, and not `SubFolder`, as you'd expect?

Comment: It returns to the inner loop but the `SubFolder` is the next one. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @mats-mug I would like it to return to the subfolder outer loop and open the file in next subfolder.

Comment: @brucewayne yes it returns t othe next item in the current subfolder but would like it to return to the next folder in the outer loop

Answer (score 1):

`Exit For` exits the current loop. Now that *current loop* is inside another, so you need a way to jump out completely.

If you want to exit *the procedure* (doesn't seem to be anything executable beyond that loop anyway), then use `Exit Sub` instead.

Otherwise (say, if you had some more code after that outer loop), you would need a separate exit mechanism on the outer loop as well, for example another `If IsExecuted Then Exit For`.

But your code is more broken than that.

`IsExecuted` is initialized to `False`, because it's declared as a `Boolean`. This means all your loop does, is enter and then immediately exit because `Not IsExecuted` evaluates to `True` already.

Unless you've removed some critical part of the code, the whole thing does strictly nothing but iterate each item in `Folder.Subfolders`.

Note that `Dim` statements aren't executable either, and in VBA the smallest possible scope is *procedure-level* - these variables:

> ```
> Dim IsExecuted As Boolean
> Dim Item
> Dim filename
> Dim lastcol As Integer
> ```

DO NOT get re-initialized at each iteration, they're in the exact same scope as `SubFolder`.

Comment: If I take out the inner loop it loops through the folders fine although the debugger doesn't actually return to the for section it just hits the following statement after that, in this case a msgbox showing the subfolder. Now I understand that the code was returning to the outer loop but it then just goes to the following statement, which is the inner loop with the other items (files) and continues to loop through them. I would ideally like to modify the inner loop to be a statement that just selects one of the files from the folder and that is all I need, then it can loop to next subfolder.